# How To Speed Up Angular Startup?

Tags: angular, performance, single-page-application, angular8, startup

I'm working on angular application, but when I build it and hosting on server it take about 3-5 minutes to start the app !!!!
so how can I fix this issue and speed up angular start up?

Comment: What do you mean by start? the loading scripts?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? Are the bundle sizes too high?

Comment: yes bundle size is too high, and it take a long time to bundle vendor.js & main.js

Comment: @DanilSabirov I mean on Startup when I try to open home page

Comment: You can also you **lazy-loading** concept in angular to reduce startup bundle size if its too high. Basically with lazy-load, load your application modules whenever user made any action that means on demand load not everything at startup time. So startup time of application will reduce.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue. Here are couple of things that I did to improve the performance of Angular App:

1. Improve images loading time images consumes most of the time while page loading so images should be compressed. I developed on the fly image compression system in AWS to handle this. 
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/appendix-d.html
2. Use change detection strategy on push in most of your components
3. Unsubscribe your observables
4. Use async tag js script tags in index.html
5. use pagination or infinite scroll loading in application